# Read all images of current tab and showing into IFrame and append frame to current page in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Read all images of current tab and bind into another page, load another page into IFrame and showing Iframe into current page in Chrome Extension
all code working fine but newTab.js file inside newTab.html not loading.

I want output like this.

[image: Output]

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "practice",
  //"icons": {
  //  "16": "icons/icon16.png",
  //  "48": "icons/icon48.png",
  //  "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  //},
  //"default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "browser action demo"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs","https://*/*", "http://*/*", "<all_urls>","activeTab","cookies","bookmarks","file://*/*","http://myapp.com/*","https://myapp.com/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*",
        "http://myapp.com/*",
        "https://myapp.com/*"
      ],      
      "css":["bootstrap.css","myscript.css"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["newTab.html"]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {    
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        var url = tabs[0].url;
        var title = tabs[0].title;
        console.log(url);       

        function getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
            chrome.cookies.get({ "url": domain, "name": name }, function (cookie) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(cookie ? cookie.value : null);
                }
            });
        }
        //usage:
        getCookies("http://myapp.com", "stakUserid", function (stakUserid) {
            if (stakUserid != null || stakUserid != undefined) {
                LoadImages();
                console.log(StackUserID);
            } else {

                RedirectToStackView(stakUserid);
            }
        });
        //chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { message: "getCookie" }, function (response) {
        //    var html = response.html;
        //    var obj = {
        //        tabUrl: url,
        //        tabHtml: html
        //    };
        //    if (html == null || html == undefined) {
        //        RedirectToStackView(obj);
        //    }

        //});
        function LoadImages() {            
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { message: "getImages" }, function (response) {
                var html = response.html;
                var obj = {
                    tabUrl: url,
                    tabTitle:title,
                    tabHtml: html
                };
                //createNewtab(obj);            


                OpenPopUp(obj);
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { message: "openModal" }, function (response) {
                    var html = response.html;
                });
            });

        }

    });
});
function RedirectToStackView(StackUserID) {
    var targetId = null;
    console.log("In New Tab " + StackUserID);
    //alert(obj.html);
    var newTabUrl = 'http://myappdemo.com:5002';

    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newTabUrl });
}
function OpenPopUp(obj) {
    var targetId = null;
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changedProps) {

        if (tabId != targetId || changedProps.status != "complete")
            return;

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "loadNewTab", data: obj });

    });


        //var newTabUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('newTab.html');
        //chrome.tabs.create({ url: newTabUrl }, function (tab) {
        //    targetId = tab.id;

        //});
}
function createNewtab(obj) {
    var targetId = null;
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changedProps) {

        if (tabId != targetId || changedProps.status != "complete")
            return;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: '/newTab.js'
        });
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "loadNewTab", data: obj });

    });

    //var newTabUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('newTab.html');
    //chrome.tabs.create({ url: newTabUrl }, function (tab) {
    //    targetId = tab.id;
    //});
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (request.message) {
        case "getImages":
            var images = [];
            var title = [];
            var pagetitle = document.title;
            var currentdocimg = document.images;
            for (var i = 0; i < currentdocimg.length; i++) {
                images.push(currentdocimg[i].src);
                title.push(currentdocimg[i].alt);
            }              

            var data = { Images: images, Title: title, PageTitle: pagetitle }
            sendResponse({ html: data });
            break;
        case "openModal":
            var iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
            iFrame.src = chrome.extension.getURL("newTab.html");
            iFrame.style = "display: block !important; width: 80% !important; height: 90% !important; top: 5% !important; right: 0px !important; overflow: hidden !important; position: fixed !important; border: 0px !important; background-color: transparent !important; z-index: 8675339 !important; left: 10% !important;";
            document.body.insertBefore(iFrame, document.body.firstChild);            
            var data = { success: "success" }
            sendResponse({ html: data });
            break;           
        case "closeModal":
            $('#myModal').modal("hide");
            break;

    }
});
```

newTab.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .navbar {
            border-radius: 0px !important;
        }

        .savebtn {
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

        .saveimagediv {
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .saveimg {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .displaynone {
            display: none;
        }



        body {
            background: #fff;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
        }

        * {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .GRID_1492146176379_hd {
            background: rgba(255,255,255,1) url(icon.png) 20px 50% no-repeat;
            color: #333;
            height: 65px;
            line-height: 65px;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 100;
            text-align: left;
            text-indent: 65px;
        }

            .GRID_1492146176379_hd .GRID_1492146176379_x {
                z-index: 10;
                opacity: .5;
                position: absolute;
                right: 25px;
                top: 0;
                cursor: pointer;
                height: 65px;
                width: 25px;
                background: transparent url(cross.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
            }

                .GRID_1492146176379_hd .GRID_1492146176379_x:hover {
                    opacity: 1;
                }

        .GRID_1492146176379_grid {
            display: block;
            margin: 72px 0 0 58px;
        }



            .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb {
                border-radius: 8px;
                margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
                display: block;
                background: #fff;
                vertical-align: top;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
                position: relative;
                border: 3px solid #fff;
            }

                .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb img {
                    border: 1px solid #fff;
                    border-radius: 8px;
                }

                    .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb img:hover {
                        border-color: red !important;
                    }

        .imageselected {
            border-color: red !important;
        }

        .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb .GRID_1492146176379_mask {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb .GRID_1492146176379_saveButton {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            width: auto;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background: #bd081c url(pin.png) 10px 9px no-repeat;
            background-size: 15px 20px;
            padding: 0 15px 0 0;
            text-indent: 26px;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 36px;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: left;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb .GRID_1492146176379_searchButton {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            height: 36px;
            width: 36px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) url(pin.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
            background-size: 20px 20px;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 100;
        }

        .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb:hover .GRID_1492146176379_saveButton, .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb:hover .GRID_1492146176379_searchButton, .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb:hover .GRID_1492146176379_ft .GRID_1492146176379_dimensions {
            opacity: 1;
        }





        .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb .GRID_1492146176379_imageless .GRID_1492146176379_site, .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb .GRID_1492146176379_imageless .GRID_1492146176379_text {
            position: absolute;
            color: #fff;
            left: 15px;
        }

        .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb .GRID_1492146176379_imageless .GRID_1492146176379_site {
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb .GRID_1492146176379_imageless .GRID_1492146176379_text {
            font-size: 19px;
            top: 38px;
            line-height: 28px;
            padding-right: 22px;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: -1px;
        }

        .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb .GRID_1492146176379_ft {
            display: block;
        }

            .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb .GRID_1492146176379_ft span {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                padding: 10px;
                color: #333;
            }

            .GRID_1492146176379_grid .GRID_1492146176379_col .GRID_1492146176379_thumb .GRID_1492146176379_ft .GRID_1492146176379_dimensions {
                border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
                padding: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: -24px;
                height: 24px;
                line-height: 24px;
                left: 0;
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
                background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 10px;
                font-style: normal;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                opacity: 0;
            }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            .mymodal-dialog
            {
                width:80% !important;
            }

        }


    </style>

    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="newTab.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Stackview</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#" id="popupclose">X</a></li>
                <!--<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h3>Select images to add</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                <div id='message' style="height: 500px;overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Title">Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" class="form-control" id="Title" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Tags">Tags:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Tags" class="form-control" id="Tags">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Price" required>Tags:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Price" class="form-control" id="Price" required>                        
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

newTab.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (request.message) {
        case "loadNewTab":           
            var StackUserID = null;
            console.log(request.data);
            images = request.data.tabHtml.Images;
            title = request.data.tabHtml.Title;
            pagetitle = request.data.tabHtml.PageTitle;
            var style = document.createElement('script');
            style.type = 'text/javascript';
            style.href = chrome.extension.getURL('bootstrap.css');
            (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(style);
            var style = document.createElement('link');
            style.rel = 'stylesheet';
            style.type = 'text/css';
            style.href = chrome.extension.getURL('bootstrap.css');
            (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(style);
            var text = "";
            if (images.length > 0) {
                //text += "<span class='GRID_1492146176379_hd'><span class='GRID_1492146176379_hdMsg'>Choose a Pin to save</span><span id='popupclose' class='GRID_1492146176379_x'></span></span>";
                text += "<span class='GRID_1492146176379_grid'>";
                //text += "<div class='row'>";

                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    if (images[i] != null && images[i] != undefined && images[i].toString() != "") {
                        text += "<div class='GRID_1492146176379_col col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'><div class='GRID_1492146176379_thumb'><img class='img img-responsive' alt='" + title[i] + "' src='" + images[i] + "'/></div></div>";
                        //<input type='button' class='GRID_1492146176379_saveButton savebtn' value='Save'/>
                        //text += "<div class='GRID_1492147712179_thumb'><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger savebtn displaynone' value='Save' /><img src='" + images[i] + "' class='img-rounded img-responsive saveimg'/></div>";
                    }
                }
                //text += "</div>";
                text += "</span>";
            }
            //if (images.length > 0) {

            //    text += "<div class='row'>";


            //    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            //        if (images[i] != null && images[i] != undefined && images[i].toString() != "") {
            //            text += "<div class='col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'><img class='img-thumbnail img img-responsive' src='" + images[i] + "'/></div>";
            //            //text += "<div class='GRID_1492147712179_thumb'><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger savebtn displaynone' value='Save' /><img src='" + images[i] + "' class='img-rounded img-responsive saveimg'/></div>";
            //        }
            //    }

            //    text += "</div>";
            //}

            console.log(text);
            var message = document.querySelector('#message');

            message.innerHTML = text;

            var Close = document.getElementById("popupclose");
            var closeFunction = function () {
                chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { message: "closeModal" }, function (response) {
                        var html = response.html;

                    });
                });

                //chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
                //    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function () { });
                //});
            };
            Close.addEventListener('click', closeFunction, false);

            //document.getElementById('popupclose').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
            var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("GRID_1492146176379_thumb");
            var myFunction = function () {
                //alert("Clicked")
                //var src = this.previousSibling.src;
                // var alt = this.alt;
                if (pagetitle != null && pagetitle != undefined) {
                    $(this).toggleClass("imageselected");
                    $("#Title").val(pagetitle);
                    // document.getElementById("Title").value = pagetitle;
                }


            };

            for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
                classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
            }
            function getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
                chrome.cookies.get({ "url": domain, "name": name }, function (cookie) {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback(cookie.value);
                    }
                });
            }

            //usage:
            getCookies("http://myapp.com", "stakUserid", function (stakUserid) {
                if (stakUserid != null || stakUserid != undefined) {
                    StackUserID = stakUserid;
                    // Loadimages();
                }
                //alert(password);
            });

            var btnadd = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
            var AddFunction = function () {
                if (StackUserID != null && StackUserID != undefined) {
                    var imgsrc = [];
                    $("#message").find('.imageselected').each(function (index) {
                        imgsrc[index] = $(this).find("img").attr("src");

                    });
                    var title = $("#Title").val().trim();
                    var tag = $("#Tags").val().trim();
                    var itemtags = [];
                    if (tag.includes(",")) {
                        itemtags = tag.split(",");
                    }
                    else {
                        itemtags = tag;
                    }
                    var price = $("#Price").val().trim();
                    if (imgsrc.length > 0) {
                        //var res = title + " " + tag + " " + price + " " + imgsrc.length
                        var postdata = {
                            "userid": StackUserID,
                            "images": imgsrc,
                            "title": title,
                            "price": price,
                            "tags": itemtags
                        }
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(postdata));
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://myapp.com/likedImages",
                            // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
                            data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
                            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {

                                alert(data.message);
                            },
                            failure: function (errMsg) {
                                alert(errMsg);
                            }
                        });                            
                    }
                } else {

                }
            };
            btnadd.addEventListener('click', AddFunction, false);
            break;
    }
});
//function clickHandler(e) {
//    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ directive: "popup-click" }, function (response) {
//        this.close(); // close the popup when the background finishes processing request
//    });
//}
```

When loading newTab.html into iframe the code inside newTab.js file not calling this will working in when open page as Newtab.

Comment: You need to declare all sub-resources loaded by newtab.html in `"web_accessible_resources"`. You can use `*` and directory names, see the documentation.

Comment: I also tryed add newTab.js file in web_accessible_resources but still i am not getting any data.in inspect the file loaded but script inside file not running...

Comment: newtab.js is not the only resource used, you need to allow all of them.

Comment: i include all scripts and css inside newTab.html but not working.